# when timer is 0 change frame

Tags: java, timer, frame

I made a timer and when it is 0 I want to change frame.
It works but the same frame keeps pop up and doesn't stops.

Check out the if and else part.

```
class SetTimer {
   private static final int TIMER_PERIOD = 1000;
   protected static final int MAX_COUNT = 5;
   private GameLuncher info;
   private int count;

   public SetTimer(GameLuncher gameLuncher) {
      this.info = gameLuncher;
      String text = " " + (MAX_COUNT - count) + " ";
      gameLuncher.setCountDownLabelText(text);
   }

   public void start() {
      new Timer(TIMER_PERIOD, new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (count < MAX_COUNT) {
               count++;
               String text = " " + (MAX_COUNT - count) + " ";
               info.setCountDownLabelText(text);
            } else  {

               ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    new GameLuncher().setVisible(false);
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);

            }
         }
      }).start();

   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David Pärsson said, "new GameLuncher().setVisible(false)" does not hide the visible GameLuncher instance already created but creates a new GameLuncher and hides it.

I suggest :

```
   ...
} else  {
   ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
   info.setVisible(false);
   new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: `new GameLuncher().setVisible(false)` does not hide the visible GameLuncher, but creates a new GameLuncher and hides that one.